# Why getters and mutations accept state and actions accept context as first argument VUEX?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Why getters and mutations accept state and actions accept context as first argument and what is the difference, having in mind that context contains all properties of the state?

Comment: Because it's designed that way? I imagine the devs feel that getters and mutators should not need access to anything else. I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect

Comment: I am asking of out curiosity, because I want to understand better, therefore I would be happy to read more about what made the devs developing Vuex make the decision they. I want to know the "why" behind and this is why I asked

Answer (score 1):

As @Phil said - this is just by design. And this design has a logical explanation:

Actions is place where data is prepared as much as possible for mutation(data can be input data or just current state), it means make http requests, transform data based on getters/state, etc.(also actions always return Promise)

Mutations are just atomic operations to change state (it can be just one line - property assignment and its ok!).

And getters are just helpers to get value based on some state property/ies.

As you can see each part is responsible for a "specific job" in Vuex store.
Getters should not change state(and of course should not call actions) just read and return some value, so getter can access just state and other getters. Mutation should change state so mutation can access only state and some input data of course. Actions need whole store context(state, getters, mutations, other actions) to allow developer to do anything with data and do final mutation.

**If each part will has access to the context - so it will be chaos in your code.**

If you faced with a problem that you need getter in your mutation - just define new action.
If you want to change state in getter - defined new action.

Also just keep in mind that you should not change directly state properties - always use mutation for this.